# Using python in conda environment does not find packages

Tags: python, pip, conda

I create a conda environment with flask installed.

```
$ conda create -n myenv
$ pip install flask
```

If I activate the environment, and run flask server, it works as expected.

```
$ conda activate myenv
(myenv)$ python myflaskapp.py
```

If I invoke flask using the python within that folder without activating the process, it does not work.

```
(myenv)$ conda deactivate
$ /path/to/myenv/Scripts/python.exe myflaskapp.py
  File "myflaskapp.py", line 1, in <module>
import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Flask'
```

I have a scenario where I want to avoid the overhead of activating the conda environment if possible, and use the conda installed folder directly. How do I do this?

Comment: To use pip to install packages, you **have** to activate the environment first. If you want to install into a non-activated environment, you have to use conda: `conda install -n myenv package`

Answer (score 0):

Check which Flask binary is used. On Linux type:

```
which flask
```

I believe on Windows

where flask

The binary should be inside you your activated conda environment path. Something like:

```
/home/USER/miniconda3/envs/ms-mint/bin/flask
```

In case you see something like:

```
/home/USER/.local/bin/flask
```

You may just delete this file. If that one is important to you, you can start Flask with the full path. Instead of `flask` use:

```
/home/USER/miniconda3/envs/ms-mint/bin/flask run
```

The problem is that the system finds another flask application first that is in a higher priority location in you `$PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, `conda` and `pip` are different package managers. If you have installed a package using `conda` in its environment, it is not accessible to you for usage in `pip` environment and vice-versa.
If you want to use Flask from `conda`, use `conda install flask`.

Comment: In the above scenrario, am using conda  to create the environment, and using pip to install flask (by default, from pypi package repo) into that conda environment. If I use `conda install flask`, it involves pulling flask from the conda package repo. However, end of the day, the env folder has its own python, pip, etc. and I assumed they are bound to the package environment in that folder.

Comment: No, it is not the way you have presented here. Conda and pip have their own set of directories, where the modules are stored. They are not interconnected (in layman terms).

Comment: Conda is certainly aware of pip installs. If you 'conda list' it will show pip installs there (they'll be marked as pip installs)

Comment: You can install pip packages in a conda environment. no problem.